# Algorithm for reducing sequence into smaller sequence (for specific function)

Tags: algorithm, sequence, reduce

I have a sequence of `(X,Y)` pairs: `(X_0,Y_0)....(X_N,Y_N)`

I add a new pair to the sequence at every time step, t

At some time in the distant future, `t_n`, I want to use a function to reduce the sequence into a number.

The function takes the sequence of pairs and an input `Z`:

```
f(Z) = ((1/X_0)-(1/Z))*Y_0 + ((1/X_1)-(1/Z))*Y_1 + ... + ((1/X_N)-(1/Z))*Y_N
```

My problem:

I don't want to store every pair of these sequences. This would require too much space.

I want to reduce the sequence into some kind of incremental representation that will allow me to

- Store much fewer pairs
- Compute `f(Z)` without any loss of precision, at any time

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `f([XYs..., (X_N, Y_N)], Z) = f(XYs..., Z) + ((1/X_N)-(1/Z))*Y_N` right?

Comment: If I'm right, you can calculate `f` on every pair addition as `f = f + (1/X_N - 1/Z) * Y_N` and just use it in every moment of time

Comment: Thanks!. But what if Z at time t_n is different than Z at time t_n-1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = 
  (1/X_0-1/Z)*Y_0 + (1/X_1-1/Z)*Y_1 = 
  (Y_0/X_0 - Y_0/Z) + (Y_1/X_1 - Y_1/Z) =
  Y_0/X_0 - Y_0/Z + Y_1/X_1 - Y_1/Z =
  Y_0/X_0 + Y_1/X_1 - Y_0/Z - Y_1/Z =
  (Y_0/X_0 + Y_1/X_1) - (Y_0 + Y_1) / Z = 
  A - B / Z

A = SUM(Y_i / X_i)
B = SUM(Y_i)
```

[image]

So you can incrementally update A and B and calculate the result in any moment of time

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted! I'm going to completely forget about X and Y and just store A and B instead. Then I can combine two entries just by simple addition. The individual X values are lost but it doesn't matter for the result.

Comment: If you were to keep some value of X (for informational purposes only), would you just take the weighted average of X's so far (weighted in terms of Y)?

Comment: @Soggiorno I do not quite understand your question